# Static constructor in Singleton design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, static-constructor

On MSDN I found two approaches to creating a singleton class:

```
public class Singleton {
   private static Singleton instance;
   private Singleton() {}
   public static Singleton Instance {
      get {
         if (instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

and

```
 public sealed class Singleton {
   private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
   private Singleton(){}
   public static Singleton Instance {
      get { return instance; }
   }
}
```

My question is: can we just use a static constructor that will make for us this object before first use?

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#nested-cctor

Comment: Read Jon Skeet's article: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx  Oops, just realized @Habib already posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use the static constructor, sure.  I don't know why you'd want to use it over just using the second example you've shown, but you certainly could.  It would be functionally identical to your second example, but just requiring more typing to get there.

Note that your first example cannot be safely used if the property is accessed from multiple threads, while the second is safe.  Your first example would need to use a `lock` or other synchronization mechanism to prevent the possibility of multiple instances being created.

Comment: Just was afraid that it is not fully identical

Comment: @user3616181 Initializers of static fields are moved into the static constructor, behind the scenes.

Comment: One more question: Why in second approach we declare singleton instance as readonly while us property has only getter?

Comment: @user3616181 You certainly don't have to.  The code would work either way.  It's primarily a signal of intent to the reader.